# Implementing a Dynamic Configuration System for EF Core ModelBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to implement a  Dynamic Configuration System for EF Core ModelBuilder as I have different EntityTypeConfiguration requirements for PostgresQL and InMemory Database.

I have created an Interface for to define my configurations.

IModelConfiguration.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace QueryHub.Application;

public interface IModelConfiguration
{
    void ApplyConfiguration(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}

public interface IModelConfiguration<T> : IModelConfiguration, IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : class
{
}
```

Here is my sample EntityTypeConfiguration:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using QueryHub.Domain.Entities;
using QueryHub.Domain.Common;

namespace QueryHub.Application.EntityTypeConfigurations;

public sealed class ExecuteQueryTaskEntityTypeConfiguration : IModelConfiguration<ExecuteQueryTask>
{
    public void ApplyConfiguration(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Configure(modelBuilder.Entity<ExecuteQueryTask>());
    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ExecuteQueryTask> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(e => e.TaskId);
        builder.Property(e => e.TaskId).ValueGeneratedNever();

        builder.Property(e => e.Status)
            .IsUnicode(false)
            .HasMaxLength(1)
            .IsFixedLength(true)
            .HasConversion(
                e => e.Value,
                e => ExecutionStatusEnum.FromValue(e));

        builder.Property(e => e.Errors)
            .HasColumnType("jsonb")
            .HasConversion(
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Error>>(v) ?? Enumerable.Empty<Error>());

        builder.Property(e => e.Parameters)
            .HasColumnType("jsonb")
            .HasConversion(
                v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(v) ?? new Dictionary<string, object>());
    }
}
```

Here is my DbContext:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using QueryHub.Application.EntityTypeConfigurations;
using QueryHub.Domain.Common;
using QueryHub.Domain.Entities;

namespace QueryHub.Application;

public interface IQueryHubDbContext
{
    DbSet<Query> Queries { get; }
    DbSet<Database> Databases { get; }
    DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; }
    DbSet<Server> Servers { get; }
    DbSet<User> Users { get; }
    DbSet<ExecuteQueryTask> ExecuteQueryTasks { get; }

    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess = true, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}

internal sealed class QueryHubDbContext(DbContextOptions<QueryHubDbContext> options, IEnumerable<IModelConfiguration> configurations) : DbContext(options), IQueryHubDbContext
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IModelConfiguration> _configurations = configurations;
    
    public DbSet<Query> Queries => Set<Query>();
    public DbSet<Database> Databases => Set<Database>();
    public DbSet<Organization> Organizations => Set<Organization>();
    public DbSet<Server> Servers => Set<Server>();
    public DbSet<User> Users => Set<User>();
    public DbSet<ExecuteQueryTask> ExecuteQueryTasks => Set<ExecuteQueryTask>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        foreach (var configuration in _configurations)
        {
            configuration.ApplyConfiguration(modelBuilder);
        }
       
    }
}
```

Here is the DI file for Application layer where my DbContext resides

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using FluentValidation;
using QueryHub.Application.Queries;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using QueryHub.Application.Servers;
using System.Reflection;
using MediatR;
using QueryHub.Application.ExecuteQueryTasks;
using QueryHub.Application.EntityTypeConfigurations;

namespace QueryHub.Application;

public sealed class ApplicationBuilder
{
    public ApplicationBuilder(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Services = services;
    }

    public IServiceCollection Services { get; }
}


public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static ApplicationBuilder AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        return new ApplicationBuilder(services);
    }

    public static ApplicationBuilder AddQueryDbContext(this ApplicationBuilder builder, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>? optionsAction = null)
    {
        var modelConfigurationType = typeof(IModelConfiguration);
        var modelConfigurationImplementations = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => modelConfigurationType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && !p.IsInterface && !p.IsAbstract)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var implementation in modelConfigurationImplementations)
        {
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(modelConfigurationType, implementation);
        }

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<IQueryHubDbContext, QueryHubDbContext>(optionsAction);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

While debugging I can see that the Configurations are getting loaded and are added as Singleton. But when i run migrations command the configurations are not getting applied.

If i added configurations directly in my DbContext using

```cs
modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ExecuteQueryTaskEntityTypeConfiguration());
```

It works.

What could be the possible solution?